# Posting form data to an iframe?

Tags: forms, iframe

I have a form that collects the users Name and Email. As of now, the form is sending the collected data to a txt file and then redirecting the user to a new page on my website, where there is an iframe.

What I want to do is also send the data to the iframe and have the data inputted into the iframe src.

This is how my form looks now:

```
<form id="subform" onSubmit="window.location='/go/' "action="http://XXXXX.com/php/subscribe-form.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
          <p>
            <input id="name" name="name" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your Name') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Name';}" value="Your Name"/>
          </p>
          <p>
            <input id="email" name="email" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Your Email') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Your Email';}" value="Your Email"  class="required email" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Click Here"/>
          </p>
          <div id="result_sub"></div>
        </fieldset>
      </form>
```

The subscribe-form.php then records the data in a txt file.

What I want to happen is to still record the data in a txt file, but also input the "name" and "email" data into the src of the iframe on "/go/"...example:

```
<iframe src="http://XXXXX.com/sample=432&name=&email="></iframe>
```

So that the "name" and "email" data that the user inputs in the form is inserted into the iframe src at `&name=` and `&email=`

How would this be done? I sincerely appreciate any help as I have been trying to figure this out for days. Thank you!